# BottomNavigation - Why does one item have different space than the rest?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I created a BottomNav with 3 normal elements and one "custom" point for a "More Menu":

[image]

But I don't understand why it would place it so differently than the others? The only difference is that the more menu is not a part of the `bottom_nav_graph.xml`, because it is a custom added item. Other than that it's just like the other items.

---

**EDIT:** With the suggestion in the comments, it really seems to work. But still, is there no way for me to **distribute the items evenly**, or make them all **equally wide** to also accomodate for long names?

[image]

---

**bottom_nav_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home_screen"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_activity_journey" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_sas"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_check_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_activity_sa" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_profile" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_more_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_horiz_24"
        android:title="@string/title_more_menu" />
</menu>
```

**bottom_nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_home_screen">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home_screen"
        android:name="com.dev.solidmind.ui.HomeScreenFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home_screen" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_sas"
        android:name="com.dev.solidmind.ui.SA_Fragment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sa"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sa" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:name="com.dev.solidmind.ui.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
</navigation>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.9"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color_selector"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Code to set up BottomNav**

```
private void setUpBottomNavigation() {
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home_screen, R.id.navigation_sas, R.id.navigation_profile, R.id.navigation_more_menu)
                .build();

        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavController navController = Objects.requireNonNull(navHostFragment).getNavController();

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavView, navController);

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> {
            if (destination.getId() == R.id.navigation_home_screen) {
                Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
            } else {
                Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).show();
            }
        });

        bottomNavView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuItem -> {
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_more_menu) {
                openBottomSheet();
                return true;
            } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_home_screen) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_home_screen);
                return true;
            } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_sas) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_sas);
                return true;
            } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_profile) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_profile);
                return true;
            } else return false;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Give same name to each menu item for testing purpose. The second item 'self-affirmation' is disturbing the width ratio I guess.

Comment: @HamzaIsrar Wow, you were right, see my edit. But still, why can I not distribute the space evenly somehow? Or make all items equally big?

Comment: It distribute the Menu evenly or let's say according to the size of the largest item. So you should you concise words and it will take care of the rest.